# Segment images with openCV

Tags: opencv

I have images in .jpg format which are segmented in three different areas by simple lines. I want to convert now these 3 areas: One area should only contain 0, and the other 1 and the third 2.
What would be the easiest way to do so?

Original image:

Image 1:

And I also have the only the annotation:

Image 2:

Comment: Post original image.

Comment: uploaded it. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Please share what you have tried

Comment: posted it. Thanks you.

Comment: please delete post